# d3-legend Lines don't Appear

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have code for a size legend from Susie Lu's legend library (http://d3-legend.susielu.com/#size):

```
var lineSize = d3.scaleLinear().domain([d3.min(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; }), d3.max(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; })]).range([d3.min(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; }), d3.max(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legendSizeLine")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20, 230)");

  var legendSizeLine = d3.legendSize()
        .scale(lineSize)
        .shape("line")
        .labelWrap(30)
        .shapeWidth(50);

  svg.select(".legendSizeLine")
    .call(legendSizeLine);
```

The code is returning the legend labels correctly, and it appears to be returning the lines correctly (based on altering `.shapeWidth`)...except the lines can't actually be seen. I think it is something wrong with the `range` in the first line of code. I have tried various ranges (including leaving it off) to no avail. What am I missing?